# How can I change the background color of a current page's navigation button/link using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I want to write a JavaScript script (**not JQuery, if at all possible**) that changes the background color of a navigation button when its page is active. In other words, when I click on the "About" link and load the page, I want the "About" button to have a different background color so the user can see which page s/he is on.

Here is my HTML for the navigation links:

```
   <nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="navbutton"><a href="../pages/about.php">About</a></li>
      <li class="navbutton"><a href="../index.php">Local services</a></li>
      <li class="navbutton"><a href="../pages/intercity.php">Intercity Services</a></li>
      <li class="navbutton"><a href="../pages/transportcircle.php">Transport Circle Overview</a></li>
      <li class="navbutton"><a href="../pages/feedback.php">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Here is the CSS rule I want to apply when the page is active:

```
.navbutton-active {
    background-color: rgb(24, 99, 6);
```

So far I've come up with this script although it isn't doing much except throw up an error:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('navbutton').addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", btnActive());

function btnActive() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('navbutton').classList.add('navbutton-active');
};
```

This is the error I get in the console:

```
TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).classList is undefined
```

The behavior I'm aiming for is the following:

1. The page loads and the corresponding navigation button background changes to the color I've specified in the `.navbutton-active` CSS declaration.
2. When the user clicks on another navigation button, the color of the active page's navigation button changes to this color and the other navigation button colors remain their default.

This is probably simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can try this :-             
`document.getElementsByClassName('navbutton').setAttribute('class','navbutton-active')`

Comment: try this: 
document.getElementsByClassName('navbutton').className = "navbutton-active";

Comment: Assuming this is not a single page app, how do you intend to check which link is active for any particular page? Surely you would need to compare the link's `href` against the current URL? Otherwise this should be done server side when the page is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Patrick, what is the best way to run that comparison? I presume I'd use an `if` loop? I don't know which methods to use to do the current page check.

Comment: @PaulJacobson, yes an if within a loop would be the approach. I have corrected my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first step would be to find out which link is the one with an `href` property that matches the current URL.

```
// Obtain a collection of all links

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.navbutton');
var activeButton, button, link, i;

// Iterate through each link to find if its href matches the URL

for (i = 0; (button = buttons[i]); i++) {
    link = button.firstElementChild;

    // a console.log(link.href, window.location.href)
    // might be useful here to ensure the comparisons will work

    if (link.href === window.location.href) {
        activeButton = button;
        break;
    }
}

// If a matching link was found, add the active class

if (activeButton) { 
     activeButton.classList.add('navbutton-active');
}
```

This URL comparison step isn't foolproof, and might need improvement. Really this should be done server side if you can.

Also the error in your original example is caused because `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like collection, which you would need to iterate through before interfacing with the `classList` property on the individual elements  (similar to querySelectorAll() in my solution, but this is the newer API).

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I used `querySelector` but it only seemed to apply the class to the first link in the navigation bar. I remember hearing that `querySelector` targets the first child element only?

Comment: Any errors? If not, firstly console.log the `links` collection, and make sure there are items. Secondly - console.log URL comparison for each link, and make sure one of them is passing.

Comment: Ok, for each one I get the following in the console:


undefined http://localhost:8888/index.php
scripts.js:34:5
NodeList [ li.navbutton, li.navbutton, li.navbutton, li.navbutton, li.navbutton ]
0 : <li class="navbutton">
1 : <li class="navbutton">
2 : <li class="navbutton">
3 : <li class="navbutton">
4 : <li class="navbutton">
length : 5
__proto__ : NodeListPrototype { item: function item(), keys: function keys(), values: function values(), … }

Comment: Ah sorry - i forgot the link is nested within the button. That's where the `.href` should be read from. Have corrected the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not there yet. I'll spend some more time on this. There must be a simple solution although I suspect the way my site is built is possibly frustrating this script.

Answer (score 0):

```
function btnActive() 
  {document.getElementById("navbutton").className = "navbutton-active ";}
```

also check if btnActive() is actually called by using `alert("testing control");` in above function

Comment: Thanks, the function runs but doesn't actually add the class and change the color.

Comment: hey.take ref from this one:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_classname  Or you can also add a small fiddle